# Rx java split infinite stream into groups and debounce each group separate

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

I have a simple class:

```
public class Event {
    String objectId;
}
```

And some event source that emitting events to my observable. This source is infinite and can send event with same objectId few times.
So, I want to group values by `objectId` and then debounce each group.
Let's say if I have
`E1-E1-E2-E1-E2-E2-E2...E2-E1-E100..`
I want to achieve:
`E1`
`E2`
..
`E2`
`E1`
`E100`
..
So, events with same `objectId` don't be emitted more than once in 1s time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take your description "So, I want to group values by objectId and then debounce each group." and directly convert it to operators:

1. "group values by objectId" -> `Observable.groupBy`
2. "debounce each group" -> `Observable.map` and `Observable.debounce`
3. and finally merge it back to a single stream -> `Observable.merge`

Turning into:

```
Observable.merge(
    <source>.groupBy(value -> value.objectId)
            .map(observable -> observable.debounce(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
)
```